# Битрикс. Вывод свойств торговых предложений в списке товаров

Tags: php, битрикс

Доброго времени суток. На сайте нужно сделать вывод свойств торговых предложений в списке товара вот тестовый сайт http://38metrov.megamir-test.ru/catalog/docke_standard/ сейчас свойства выводятся, но, фото свойства у всех одно и тоже, хотя значения разные у торг. предложения. Формируется вывод свойств в result_modifier.php вот код

```
foreach($arResult["SKU_PROPS"] as $keySKU => $arSKUProps){ //  свойство цвет 1  
foreach($arResult['ITEMS'] as $key => $arItem) {  // елементы раздела 



    foreach ($arItem["JS_OFFERS"] as $keyOff => $arOffers) // торг. пред.
    {


        if ($arSKUProps["VALUES"][$arOffers["TREE"]["PROP_".$arSKUProps["ID"]]])  // проверка елси совпадает свойство ТП из массива "свойств ТП" с массивом самих ТП
        {
            if ($arOffers["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]) // если у ТП есть картинка Анонса 
            {


                // если нашли картинку, то дабавляем ее в массив со свойствами ТП


                $arResult["SKU_PROPS"][$keySKU]["VALUES"][$arOffers["TREE"]["PROP_".$arSKUProps["ID"]]]["D_IMG"] = $arOffers['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC'];

                $arResult["SKU_PROPS"][$keySKU]["VALUES"][$arOffers["TREE"]["PROP_".$arSKUProps["ID"]]]["D_IMG"] = $arOffers['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC'];


            }else{


                $arResult["SKU_PROPS"][$keySKU]["VALUES"][$arOffers["TREE"]["PROP_".$arSKUProps["ID"]]]["IMG"] = "N";
                $arResult["SKU_PROPS"][$keySKU]["VALUES"][$arOffers["TREE"]["PROP_".$arSKUProps["ID"]]]["D_IMG"] = "N";
            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

на выходе получается массив (пример отрывка т.к массив очень большой):

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 468
            [CODE] => cvet
            [NAME] => Цвет 1
            [SORT] => 24
            [PROPERTY_TYPE] => L
            [USER_TYPE] => 
            [LINK_IBLOCK_ID] => 0
            [USER_TYPE_SETTINGS] => 
            [VALUES] => Array
                (
                   5205] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5205
                            [NAME] => Роза бледно-пурпурная
                            [SORT] => 500
                            [PICT] => 
                        )

                    [3926] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 3926
                            [NAME] => Пломбир
                            [SORT] => 500
                            [PICT] => 
                            [D_IMG] => /upload/iblock/3b4/3b4bcfc3259f14248d29e53e1ee48cdd.gif
                            [IMG] => /upload/iblock/3b4/3b4bcfc3259f14248d29e53e1ee48cdd.gif
                        )

                    [4182] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 4182
                            [NAME] => Чарли
                            [SORT] => 500
                            [PICT] => 
                        )

                    [4438] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 4438
                            [NAME] => Fels Северная скала
                            [SORT] => 500
                            [PICT] => 
                        )

                        )

                    [4116] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 4116
                            [NAME] => Дуб Парана
                            [SORT] => 500
                            [PICT] => 
                        )
      )
)
```

т.е из кода выше если находим торг.пред с таким же id свойства, то присваиваем в массив свойств, картинку этого ТП. 
И все работает нормально если нет совпадений id из массива свойств и id свойств торг.перд.

К примеру если попадается у какого то ТП свойство цвет со значением "Пломбир" то оно перезатрет предыдущее значение этого же свойства т.е картинку.

Я пытался сделать так, участок этого кода:

```
$arResult["SKU_PROPS"][$keySKU]["VALUES"][$arOffers["TREE"]["PROP_".$arSKUProps["ID"]]]["D_IMG"] = $arOffers['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC'];

$arResult["SKU_PROPS"][$keySKU]["VALUES"][$arOffers["TREE"]["PROP_".$arSKUProps["ID"]]]["IMG"] = $arOffers['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC'];
```

заменить на этот:

```
$arResult["SKU_PROPS"][$keySKU]["VALUES"][$arOffers["TREE"]["PROP_".$arSKUProps["ID"]]]["IMG"][$arOffers['ID']] = $arOffers["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"];

$arResult["SKU_PROPS"][$keySKU]["VALUES"][$arOffers["TREE"]["PROP_".$arSKUProps["ID"]]]["IMG"][$arOffers['ID']] = $arOffers["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"];
```

в результате получаю массив:

```
            [3926] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 3926
                    [NAME] => Пломбир
                    [SORT] => 500
                    [PICT] => 
                    [D_IMG] => Array
                        (
                            [14525] => /upload/iblock/12a/12aaeb90d9e4003b3f673552c4f8bede.gif
                            [14499] => /upload/iblock/424/424e44168f99ef40be8a5e010f27b001.gif
                            [17017] => /upload/iblock/18e/18e84c20c60efcab3d66613d36b5122e.gif
                            [15442] => /upload/iblock/1ff/1ff0c1ce9ae2a039a9b0f5558d297996.gif
                            [15586] => /upload/iblock/30a/30afa3febe7d1791391af50038ac5732.gif
                            [14351] => /upload/iblock/c02/c02cca4ce8ce430bfb5342f9821028ab.gif
                            [14346] => /upload/iblock/eed/eed004c7420d9c9c11c75a223fa32723.gif
                            [16774] => /upload/iblock/ba4/ba40fddc2cc389c4846d49ec8ba32c74.gif
                            [17331] => /upload/iblock/b58/b5861e59ed9d7cafe05b5f6ae9562821.gif
                            [14510] => /upload/iblock/790/790dd3320d5b6b7fbc3ea0ffcd552560.gif
                            [17021] => /upload/iblock/95e/95ecef363664ea80f78af121a5559311.gif
                            [14088] => /upload/iblock/4c4/4c407a287a93cffa73397006faf8d947.gif
                            [16814] => /upload/iblock/9e1/9e13dae742cb8940fad33712b00d2a06.gif
                            [13068] => /upload/iblock/6ca/6cab30e397e949018a41d1497efa8714.gif
                            [14046] => /upload/iblock/9bd/9bdca3a1613dbf29ee79a6945bd67628.gif
                            [16997] => /upload/iblock/3b4/3b4bcfc3259f14248d29e53e1ee48cdd.gif
                        )

                    [IMG] => Array
                        (
                            [14525] => /upload/iblock/12a/12aaeb90d9e4003b3f673552c4f8bede.gif
                            [14499] => /upload/iblock/424/424e44168f99ef40be8a5e010f27b001.gif
                            [17017] => /upload/iblock/18e/18e84c20c60efcab3d66613d36b5122e.gif
                            [15442] => /upload/iblock/1ff/1ff0c1ce9ae2a039a9b0f5558d297996.gif
                            [15586] => /upload/iblock/30a/30afa3febe7d1791391af50038ac5732.gif
                            [14351] => /upload/iblock/c02/c02cca4ce8ce430bfb5342f9821028ab.gif
                            [14346] => /upload/iblock/eed/eed004c7420d9c9c11c75a223fa32723.gif
                            [16774] => /upload/iblock/ba4/ba40fddc2cc389c4846d49ec8ba32c74.gif
                            [17331] => /upload/iblock/b58/b5861e59ed9d7cafe05b5f6ae9562821.gif
                            [14510] => /upload/iblock/790/790dd3320d5b6b7fbc3ea0ffcd552560.gif
                            [17021] => /upload/iblock/95e/95ecef363664ea80f78af121a5559311.gif
                            [14088] => /upload/iblock/4c4/4c407a287a93cffa73397006faf8d947.gif
                            [16814] => /upload/iblock/9e1/9e13dae742cb8940fad33712b00d2a06.gif
                            [13068] => /upload/iblock/6ca/6cab30e397e949018a41d1497efa8714.gif
                            [14046] => /upload/iblock/9bd/9bdca3a1613dbf29ee79a6945bd67628.gif
                            [16997] => /upload/iblock/3b4/3b4bcfc3259f14248d29e53e1ee48cdd.gif
                        )

                )
```

т.е чтобы каждому тп присваивалась своя картинка и свойства не перезатирались

в шаблоне вывод организован так:

```
  foreach ($arResult['SKU_PROPS'] as &$arProp){

    // foreach($arResult['ITEMS'] as $key => $arItem) {  добавил циклы чтобы по ID торг. предложения цеплять нужную картинку

        // foreach ($arItem["JS_OFFERS"] as $keyOff => $arOffers) 
        // {


ob_start();

if ('L' == $arProp['PROPERTY_TYPE'])
{
if (5 < $arProp['VALUES_COUNT'])
{
    $strClass = 'bx_item_detail_size full';
    $strSlideStyle = '';
}
else
{
    $strClass = 'bx_item_detail_size';
    $strSlideStyle = 'display: none;';
}

?>

<div class="<? echo $strClass; ?>" id="#ITEM#_prop_<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>_cont">
<b>
     <?php
$propert = $arProp['NAME'];
if ($propert == "Цвет 1") {
        $propert = "Цвет";
 }
     echo $propert.":";?></b>

<span class="bx_item_section_name_gray"><? echo htmlspecialcharsex($arProp['NAME']); ?></span>

<div class="bx_size_scroller_container">
<div class="bx_size">

<ul id="#ITEM#_prop_<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>_list" >

<?foreach ($arProp['VALUES'] as $arOneValue){

    ?>
            <li
                data-treevalue="<? echo $arProp['ID'].'_'.$arOneValue['ID']; ?>"
                data-onevalue="<? echo $arOneValue['ID']; ?>"
                data-pic="<?=$arOneValue['D_IMG'][$arOffers['ID']] // вывод картинки ?>"
                data-offer-id="<?=$arOffers['ID']?>"
            >
            <? if ($arOneValue['IMG'] != "N") { ?>


                <span style="display: inline-block;width: 24px; height: 24px; background: url(<?=$arOneValue['IMG']?>) no-repeat center;"></span>


            <? }else{ ?>
                <span style="display: inline-block;"></span>
            <? } ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><? echo $arOneValue['NAME']; ?></a>
            </li>


<?}?>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="bx_slide_left" id="#ITEM#_prop_<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>_left" data-treevalue="<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>" style="<? echo $strSlideStyle; ?>"></div>
<div class="bx_slide_right" id="#ITEM#_prop_<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>_right" data-treevalue="<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>" style="<? echo $strSlideStyle; ?>"></div>
</div>


</div><?
            }
            elseif ('E' == $arProp['PROPERTY_TYPE'])
            {
                if (5 < $arProp['VALUES_COUNT'])
                {
                    $strClass = 'bx_item_detail_scu full';
                    $strWidth = ($arProp['VALUES_COUNT']*20).'%';
                    $strOneWidth = (100/$arProp['VALUES_COUNT']).'%';
                    $strSlideStyle = '';
                }
                else
                {
                    $strClass = 'bx_item_detail_scu';
                    $strSlideStyle = 'display: none;';
                }
                ?><div class="<? echo $strClass; ?>" id="#ITEM#_prop_<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>_cont">
<div class="bx_scu_scroller_container"><div class="bx_scu"><ul id="#ITEM#_prop_<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>_list" ><?
                foreach ($arProp['VALUES'] as $arOneValue)
                {
                    ?><li
                        data-treevalue="<? echo $arProp['ID'].'_'.$arOneValue['ID'] ?>"
                        data-onevalue="<? echo $arOneValue['ID']; ?>"
                    >
                        <span></span><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span></span></a></li><?
                }
?></ul></div>
        <div class="bx_slide_left" id="#ITEM#_prop_<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>_left" data-treevalue="<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>" style="<? echo $strSlideStyle; ?>"></div>
        <div class="bx_slide_right" id="#ITEM#_prop_<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>_right" data-treevalue="<? echo $arProp['ID']; ?>" style="<? echo $strSlideStyle; ?>"></div>
    </div>
</div><?
            }
            $arSkuTemplate[$arProp['CODE']] = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
}
//}}
```

Извиняюсь что такие портянки сюда выкладываю. Мне нужна помощь , не могу до конца сообразить, что делаю не так, т.к на выходе получается тоже самое. И вообще как лучше можно решить проблему  ? Спасибо за любую помощь.